# Change number of column family is not working

Tags: hbase

I have a table named 'emp' in HBase. Then I use below command to change the number of column family's version but seems it's not working, I can see only one version while I using scan command:

```
hbase(main):040:0> alter 'emp', {NAME=>'personal data',VERSIONS=>5}
Updating all regions with the new schema...
0/1 regions updated.
1/1 regions updated.
Done.
0 row(s) in 3.2160 seconds

hbase(main):041:0> put 'emp', '1', 'personal data:phone', '153'
0 row(s) in 0.0400 seconds

hbase(main):042:0> scan 'emp'
ROW                                  COLUMN+CELL
 1                                   column=personal data:phone, timestamp=1528010315683, value=153
1 row(s) in 0.0190 seconds

hbase(main):043:0> put 'emp', '1', 'personal data:phone', '159'
0 row(s) in 0.0320 seconds

hbase(main):044:0> scan 'emp'
ROW                                  COLUMN+CELL
 1                                   column=personal data:phone, timestamp=1528010347794, value=159
1 row(s) in 0.0340 seconds
```

Actually, I should see two versions when I use the scan command for the second time. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
scan 'emp', { VERSIONS => 5}
```

PS: the recommendation is to have short names for Column Families (typically 1 or 2 letters) because it takes disk spaces at the end; so "personal data" is probably not a good idea

Comment: And definitely don't have a space in the column family. I'm surprised it's even permitted.